# save column values from a Word Table with Python with docx library

Tags: python, ms-word

How can I print just the values in the second column in a MS word table.
My code is below prints first column value,second column values
one below the other.
Example:Word Table format:

```
colm 1       column2
SR#          32213
Part#        K9843
PartDesc     SteamBolt
```

---my code---

```
import docx
from docx import Document
wordDoc = Document('c:\python-programs\ssis-test.docx')
for table in wordDoc.tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            print (cell.text)
```

---end my code---
The above code prints as below.

```
SR#
32213
Part# 
K9843
PartDesc
SteamBolt
```

I want only to print values `32213, K9843` and `SteamBolt` (in the second column only.)

Python version: `3.5.2` with docx library.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Docx is probably not the best approach as it only offers a small subset of the Word api and despite appearances on GitHub, hasn't been significantly developed for a number of years.

A better approach would be to use Win32Com which gives full access to Com object models (such as office applications).  With Win32com you'd also want to use makepy to generate the intellisense for the object model you wish to use.

Having a quick look here will help

http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/html/com/win32com/HTML/QuickStartClientCom.html

The VBA approach to your question would be

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim my_table                    As Word.Table
    Dim my_row                      As Word.Row
    Dim my_text                     As String

    For Each my_table In ActiveDocument.Tables

        For Each my_row In my_table.Range.Rows

            my_text = my_row.Range.Cells(2)

        Next

    Next

End Sub
```

But this is not guaranteed as Word has problematical table handling if your Table contains cells that have been merged.  You can test for a Table that will give problems using the .Uniform property.  How you deal with a non uniform Table is something I'll leave you to research if you need to.